# Applet closes automatically

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a very simple java applet which reads the audio files data from user directory.

I am using applet function in javascript. The problem is my applet closes after 15 seconds automatically and hence the function is not called.

I have signed the applet. Certificate is also generated but applet (more precise file chooser ) closes after 15 seconds.

Any help?

Comment: is there any exception or any message on java applet console ?

Comment: nope. Nothing at all. It just crashes. Console goes away and nothing is there.

Comment: Does this happen with appletviewer too?

Comment: nah. It crashes only when I use it in browser. Otherwise, it is happy in getting opened and staying there for hours.

Answer (score 0):

> ..I am using applet function in javascript

When mixing JS and trusted code, it is necessary to wrap that code in a [AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged%28java.security.PrivilegedAction%29) method.  Since appletviewer does not support JS, that suggests why AV can open it, whereas a browser might not be able to.

Comment: well. I did it via AccessController.doPriviliged(PriviligedAction). But still it is not in operational form. Still it vanishes after 15 seconds.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html) that demonstrates the stated behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Alright people, I found the solution. :)

The problem occurs when we use java applet function in javascript. Javascript runs after 15 seconds of page load and this time is left for applet I suppose. When we call the function of applet, it comes up with an error.

So, I changed the algorithm to achieve my requirements. Now I have put all the javascript in one function and I call it from applet. simple!